# How to solve system of set-theoretic equations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Consider the next setup:
$S = \{a,b,c,d,e\}, A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2,X_1,X_2 ⊂ S$

$(A_1\setminus X_1) \cup X_2 = B_1$
$(A_2\setminus X_1) \cup X_2 = B_2$

\ is [relative complement.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) $\{a,b\} \setminus \{a\} = \{b\} $

How to find all possible solutions for $X_1, X_2$? What is the right mathematical name for such equations?

Example:

$(\{a,b,c\}\setminus X_1) \cup X_2 = \{b,c\}$

$(\{a,b,c\} \setminus \{a\}) \cup \{c\} = \{b,c\}$

$(\{a,d,e\} \setminus \{a\}) \cup \{c\} = \{d,e,c\}$

My idea was to use equation 1 to express $X_2$ in terms $X_1$ and substitute $X_2$ in equation 2.

But I am stuck with what to do next.

$X_2 = B_1 \setminus (A_1 \setminus X_1)$

$X_1 = A_2 \setminus (B_2 \setminus (B_1 \setminus (A_1 \setminus X_1)))$

Comment: As far as I know this type is called set-theoretic equations.

Comment: @MaximNikitin I can not find anything related by googling 'set-theoretic equations'. Can you please provide any link to get started (wiki, book,...)?

Comment: I am not sure there a specific theory dedicated to these equations. All that one can is to use set-theoretic identities or definitions of the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your universe, i.e. the number of primal elements is finite, you can recast any set operation as a boolean logical operation.

That way, you can transform any set formula over the universe into a propositional formula.

In your case $S=\{1,..,5\}$ is the universe.

Define for every set $X\subseteq X$ the binary variables $X^1$,...,$X^5$.

The idea behind these variables is that $X^i = 1\Leftrightarrow 1\in X$.

Now we create variables $\varphi_i$ with binary variables $\varphi_i^k$, k=1,...,5 for every partial formula and connect them to our original variables:

$\varphi_1 := A_1\setminus x_1$

$\varphi_1^k \Leftrightarrow A_1^k \land \lnot x_1^k$

$\varphi_2:=\varphi_1\cup x_2$

$ \varphi_2^k \Leftrightarrow \varphi_1^k\lor x_2^k$

$\varphi_3:=\varphi_2=B$

$\varphi_3^k \Leftrightarrow (\varphi_2^k\Leftrightarrow B_1^k)$

We now simplify $\varphi_3^k$ by applying the substituions $... \Leftrightarrow ...$:

$\varphi_3^k
\equiv \varphi_2^k\Leftrightarrow B_1^k 
\equiv (\varphi_1^k\lor x_2k)\Leftrightarrow B_1^k 
\equiv ((A_1^k \land \lnot x_1^k)\lor x_2^k)\Leftrightarrow B_1^k 
$

You then do the same for the other equation for another variable $\psi$.

Having done this, you'll now need to solve the propositional formula
$$
\left(\bigwedge_{k=1}^5 \varphi_3^k\right) \land \left(\bigwedge_{k=1}^5 \psi_3^k\right)  
$$

. More precisely, you're looking for a substitution of $x_1^k, x_2^k$ k=1,...,5  which makes the formula true.

You can further simplify the formula by realizing that  $\left(\bigwedge_{k=1}^5 \varphi_3^k\right) \land \left(\bigwedge_{k=1}^5 \psi_3^k\right) $ can be decomposed into 5 independent formulas $\varphi_3^k\land \psi_3^k$ for $k=1,...,5$:

(This should always be the case, no matter the formula, so as partial general result we obtain, that the size of our universe $S$ doesn't matter)
$$
\varphi_3^k\land \psi_3^k \equiv (((A_1^k \land \lnot x_1^k)\lor x_2^k)\Leftrightarrow B_1^k) \land (((A_2^k \land \lnot x_1^k)\lor x_2^k)\Leftrightarrow B_2^k ) 
$$
(From now on, I'll drop the exponent $k$, to save me some writing)

Rewriting this into DNF gives you the full solution, however it does so as case function. The DNF is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&(¬ x_2 ∧ ¬ x_1 ∧ ¬ A_1 ∧ A_2 ∧ ¬ B_1 ∧ B_2) 
\\ &∨(¬ x_2 ∧ ¬ x_1 ∧ A_1 ∧ ¬ A_2 ∧ B_1 ∧ ¬ B_2) 
\\&∨ (¬ x_2 ∧ ¬ A_1 ∧ ¬ A_2 ∧ ¬ B_1 ∧ ¬ B_2) 
\\&∨ (¬ x_2 ∧ x_1 ∧ ¬ A_1 ∧ ¬ B_1 ∧ ¬ B_2)
\\ &∨ (¬ x_2 ∧ x_1 ∧ ¬ B_1 ∧ ¬ B_2)
\\ &∨ (x_2 ∧ ¬ x_1 ∧ A_1 ∧ B_1 ∧ B_2)
\\ &∨ (x_2 ∧ B_1 ∧ B_2)
\\ &∨ (¬ x_1 ∧ A_1 ∧ A_2 ∧ B_1 ∧ B_2)
\end{aligned}$$

For example the disjunction $¬ x_2 ∧ ¬ x_1 ∧ ¬ A_1 ∧ A_2 ∧ ¬ B_1 ∧ B_2$ gives you the case, that when $A_1=0, A_2=1, B_=0, B_2=1$ we have $x_1=0, x_2=0$.

We can "unclausify" this as follows:

- Fix $i\in\{1,2\}$.
- Delete all clauses without $x_i$.
- Delete $x_1,x_2, \lnot x_1, \lnot x_2$ from all clauses.

The resulting formula now describes $x_i$, and replacing the logical operators by the corresponding set operators gives you the set formula for $x_i$ that is maximally true, i.e. it only doesn't hold, if for the partial evaluation of $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ no possible assignments of $X_1,X_2$ makes the formula true.

Finally, you should test whether the formula is a tautology (by checking if the negated formula is satisfiable).

The only problem with this solution is that in general, the solution size is exponential in the number of variables.

In return however, you can always find a solution using this method.

---

For example, with the DNF given above, we obtain

$x_2=( A_1 ∧ B_1 ∧ B_2) ∨ ( B_1 ∧ B_2) = B_1 ∧ B_2$

$x_1=(¬ A_1 ∧ ¬ B_1 ∧ ¬ B_2) ∨ (¬ B_1 ∧ ¬ B_2) = ¬ B_1 ∧ ¬ B_2 $

Substituting $x_1,x_2$ in the formula $(((A_1 \land \lnot x_1)\lor x_2)\Leftrightarrow B_1) \land (((A_2 \land \lnot x_1)\lor x_2)\Leftrightarrow B_2 ) $, and testing whether
$$ \lnot \bigg((((A_1 \land \lnot x_1)\lor x_2)\Leftrightarrow B_1) \land (((A_2 \land \lnot x_1)\lor x_2)\Leftrightarrow B_2 ) \bigg)$$
is satisfiable, gives us that e.g. $B_2=A_1=0 \land B_1=1$ satisfies above formula.

From this we can construct a counter example for our original set equation:

Let $S = \{a\}, A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2,X_1,X_2 ⊂ S$

and

$B_2=A_1=\emptyset$, $B_1=\{a\}$.

Then we have

$(\emptyset\setminus X_1) \cup X_2 = B_1 \rightarrow X_2=B_1 \rightarrow X_2=\{a\}$

$(A_2\setminus X_1) \cup X_2 = \emptyset\rightarrow X_2=\emptyset$

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. To be honest it is a little bit hard for me to understand it completely. Can you please suggest a book to study needed material? Is it some common problem or did you come up with solution from scratch?

Comment: Please correct: for example: U={a,b,c}, A1={a,b}=110, B1={b,c}=011, X1={a}=100, X2={c}=001 Equations become: (A1 AND NOT X1) OR X2 = B1, (110 AND NOT 100) OR 001 = 011, (010 OR 001) = 011. Use SAT to solve (Equation1 AND Equation2) for X1, X2.

Comment: I've made it up from scratch, and yes, there was an error in my logic. It should be fixed now. The key idea is that each clause in the DNF is a partial evaluation that makes the formula true, and all such partial evaluations are covered by the DNF. So e.g. the clause $x_1\land x_2 \land B_1\land B_2$ forces $x_1$ to be true if $B_1\land B_2$ is true. We do this by setting $x_1=1$ if $B_1\land B_2=1$.  The formula we then construct for $x_1$ this way makes $x_1$ in each clause of the DNF redundant, i.e. the formula can  be eliminated from each clause by logical equivalent transformations.

Comment: You have inspired me to study logic deeper. If it would be one book what would you suggest?

Comment: The computational aspects of propositional logic are nicely explained in "Mathematical Logic for Computer Science" from Mordechai. Chapter 5 actually develops a framework which can be used for this type of problem (The problem type is called  "quantified propositional logic"). Be aware though that they do not, and most classic books on logic hardly,  work with the DNF (it mostly pops up in computer engineering).

Comment: I have read the book and understand your answers in most parts now. It is not clear why your full solution in DNF form is different from that I get from [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DNF+%28+%28%28a1+and+not+x1%29+or+x2%29+%3C%3D%3E+b1%29+and+%28%28%28a2+and+not+x1%29+or+x2%29+%3C%3D%3E+b2%29)

Comment: @OlegDats That is because only the canonical DNF is unique. The minimal DNF (i.e. the shortest DNF formula) needn't be unique, and because it's NP-complete to derive a minimal DNF, some solvers might use heuristics and might not even find the minimal DNF, but just some DNF that's somewhere in between (like mine did). Here a link that shows that they're equivalent: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/573f1c43-1dae-4fe6-82d1-fc25bc4f712b ;

Comment: You have derived $x_2= B_1 ∧ B_2$ Can you please explain why in Truth table there exist row where $F=True, B_1=True, B_2=True,  B_1 ∧ B_2 = True, but x_2 = False$?

Comment: Can you please explain how did you derive "unclausify" algorithm? Why is it ok to "Delete all clauses without $x_i$"? If not to delete then expressions for $x_1$ and $x_2$ will contain $a_1 ∨ ¬a_1$

Comment: Do I understand correctly: 
1) $x_2 \Leftrightarrow B_1 \land B_2$ is not implication from main DNF but a separate formula that is consistent with main DNF.
2) In "unclausify" algorithm we can use $\lnot x_i$ except $x_i$ and derive working formula $\lnot x_i  \Leftrightarrow ...$